# What does the "Blocking temporarily off" Phone notification mean?

Tags: notifications, phone-app

After calling an emergency number, I received a notification from the "Phone" app on my Android device that states:

> Blocking temporarily off
> Blocking is turned off after you dial or text an emergency number

[image: "Blocking is turned off" notification]

Not to be dense or pedantic, but there's no noun there: the blocking of *what*, specifically, is turned off? Is it the blocking of calls, maybe? Is it disabling the blocking of caller-ID numbers on my side or their side (or both)?

In other words, what is the normal behavior in the Phone app being altered (i.e. what would I, or someone else, otherwise have been able to "block")?

Answer (score 2):

This is about **blocking receiving calls**.

Apparently, this behavior has been observed since 2016. [An article on Android Police](https://www.androidpolice.com/2016/05/13/call-blocking-is-now-automatically-disabled-for-48-hours-after-you-call-an-emergency-number/) provided an introduction about this behavior.

> [image]
>
> Apparently if you call an emergency number from your Android device, you can't block calls for the next 48 hours.
>
> We don't know why this is the case, though we imagine it may be to prevent you from blocking your local police department or other emergency personnel.
>
> The notification appears at the top of the Call Blocking screen. It does not provide a rationale, nor is this all that happens after you call for help. [...]

---

[Google Fi Help](https://support.google.com/fi/answer/6357767?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccall-blocking-and-emergency-services) also mentioned about this behavior.

> **Call blocking and emergency services (911)**
>
> If you make an emergency call, Google Fi will turn off all number blocking for a 2-hour period to make sure that 911 operators can call you back if needed.
>
> To turn off number blocking temporarily, Google Fi sends a data message, and in some cases a text message, to our servers to let us know an emergency call was made from your device.